# Unable to do-release-upgade linux because python 3.10 packages are unupgradeable

Tags: upgrade, updates, python, zoom-meeting, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to do-release-upgrade to 23.04 but I'm unable to

```
do-release-upgrade
```

because python 3.10 packages are unupgradeable
I'm not sure if it's related but I can't run neither zoom nor teams on this OS which is my main motivation for an upgrade.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates
for your release before upgrading. 
root@:~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib python3.10 python3.10-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

So I tried upgrading libpython3.10-stdlib which seems like the base package which leads to a libssl issue and a fixing that leads to  libpython3.10-stdlib : Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages

```
sudo apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 upgrade libpython3.10-stdlib

Reading package lists... Done
```

> ...

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.11-1+focal1) but 3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
                        Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but it is not installable
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.7-1ubuntu0.3) but 3.10.11-1+focal1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Did you somehow update Python to a non-standard version earlier? This can lead to unexpected problems.

Comment: Changing the python interpreter can be a system killer. You may need to reinstall the OS.  Don't change the python interpreter on your system. Use virtual environments instead.

Comment: Totally right about not changing system python interpreter but I'm trying to work throught this!  I did find a problem with libssl

Comment: Did you use `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` to change the system python interpreter or did you uninstall the default python version? If you uninstalled the default python version you need to reinstall it and run `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`  and select it as the default version again.

Comment: @karel that returns "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3.10" even though 3.8, 3.9 and 3.12 are installed.

Comment: You have some type of PPA enabled right now which supersedes the system Python.  `3.10.11-1+focal1` is NOT an Ubuntu version string, it's a PPA or otherwise.  Show the output of `apt-cache policy python3.10` before continuing to debug this.  You have *something* providing Python 3.10 that is not the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Thomas if you care to post this as an answer I will accept it as correct.